# Deprecated hash replacement

Tags: php, plugin

EE is warning about a deprecated function from the NCE LDAP plugin:

```
$encrypted_password = $this->EE->functions->hash(stripslashes($user_info['password']));
```

I see the replacement below, but can't quite figure out how to rewrite this line to use the do_hash...and work.  Anyone able to rewrite this?
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/security_helper.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [changelog](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/changelog.html#version-2-6-0) says:

> Deprecated methods:
>   Security helper’s do_hash(), use PHP’s hashing functions instead.
>   Removed Methods:
>   Functions::hash()

The link you provide shows that do_hash() uses SHA1 by default. So:

```
$encrypted_password = hash('sha1',stripslashes($user_info['password']));
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you!!  That saved hours...